# dpkg: error processing package php5-mysql (--configure):

Tags: apache2, php, mysql

When installing PHP and mySQL, I got the following error message. What to do?

```
Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini with new version
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini’: No such      file or directory
dpkg: error processing package php5-mysql (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php5 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14) ...
Errors were encountered while processing: php5-mysql
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when i removed mysql-server and tried to reinstall.
The way i solved this was by running the following

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client-5.6 mysql-server-5.6 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql

sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
```

- Link apparmor:

  `sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.sbin.mysqld`

  `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart`
- Install MySQL 5.6:

  `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6`